# How to redirect to LogIn page when Session is expired (ASP.NET 3.5 FormsAuthen)

Tags: asp.net

I'm using FormsAuthentication and ASP.Net SqlMembership Provider. I would like to provide a functionality to redirect to LogIn page when the underlying Session is expired.

I put the following block of codes in my **BasePage OnInit**. As far as I tested, it always keeps on redirecting to LogIn page even though I supplied correct UserID and Password. By rights, it should take me to default page.

```
if (Context.Session != null && Session.IsNewSession && this.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string cookieHeader = Request.Headers["Cookie"];
            if (cookieHeader != null && cookieHeader.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0)
            {


                    HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();                       
                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();                        
                    Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);                                           

            }
        }
```

Comment: Isn't this functionality built in to Forms authentication anyway?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need any custom code for this functionality, it's supported by the Framework. Just configure it in the web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx"
        loginUrl="~/Login.aspx"
        slidingExpiration="true"
        timeout="60" />
</authentication>
```

With the configuration above, the user will be always redirected to the Login.aspx page when their session expires. There is a timeout of 60 minutes, and sliding expiration means that the timeout is extended each time the user makes a request to the web application, so if he stays active the session will not expire. A configuration like this gives you another advantage over what you tried to do - once the user logs in he will be automatically redirected back to the resource he originally requested. And you can always override and customize this behavior.

Comment: Hi Pawel Krakowiak,

   I DO appreciate you for your answer. :)
   In fact, I've already done the same configurations you mentioned above. :( But I don't know what has gotten into my mind to do custom coding to cater for the already-existed functionality.

Regards,
Kyaw Thurein

Comment: Let's say this happens when they click a Save button on a form that does a postback, they are directed to login page, then login and go back to the original resource.  Will the postback then be complete so that the form data can be processed as usual?

Comment: @aaronls: No, the data will be lost. Only the requested URL is remembered.

Comment: @PawelKrakowiak I tried to use your code in my web.config, but why it throw me HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error at <authentication mode="Forms">?? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @LstPatrick That doesn't tell a lot. You need to check the actual error message / stack trace to see what's going on. Maybe you have a config error (config element in wrong spot, etc.).

Comment: @PawelKrakowiak I see, the code above will redirect it self as long as session expire or need to click any button to trigger it?

Comment: I don't know in web config , where can we add this code?

Answer (score 15):

[Pawel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654005/how-to-redirect-to-login-page-when-session-is-expired-asp-net-3-5-formsauthen/654138#654138) is partially correct, but you also need to set the `Session` lifetime to a value longer than the forms authentication cookie lifetime as well. The forms authentication `timeout` value only affects the lifetime of the authentication cookie. In the example he provided, the authentication cookie lifetime is 60 minutes but the default session lifetime is 20 minutes. If a user left their machine for more than 20 minutes their session data would be discarded, subsequent attempts to reference a value stored in session would result in an exception being thrown (for example `System.NullReferenceException` if attempting to `.ToString()` or a cast).

You can set this globally in your application by configuring the [`sessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx) settings in your web.config file:

```
<sessionState 
    mode="InProc" 
    cookieless="false" 
    timeout="70"/>
```

Adding five or ten minutes to the session timeout provides a good buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation. It is indeed important when you're using session variables. I just have a habit of paranoidally checking for their existence/value before I try to use them. ;)

Comment: I know...it's a shame they don't have a signoutIfSessionExpired="true" setting.

Comment: Hi Kev,

   I really thank you for your advice.

Regards,
Thurein

Comment: Would this work for when the session expires for any other reason, like when the web.config file is changes, for instance?

Comment: @Marlon - if the session has been abandoned (such as when the app restarts) before the auth cookie has expired then you'd need to handle that condition.