# Is it possible to make auto lock screen in ASP.NET-MVC-4 Razor View ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

can i make my admin website auto lock when the admin/user don't do anything between 10 minutes in razor view ?

this is my lock screen controller

```
public ActionResult LockScreen (User user) 
{ 
user.NamaUser = AppServices.NamaUser; 
user.KodePassword = AppServices.Password; 
return View(); 
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LockScreen (User user)
{
if (user.KodePassword == AppServices.Password)
{
return RedirectToAction ("Index","Home");
}
return View();
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into sessions [asp-net-mvc-4-session-timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209072/asp-net-mvc-4-session-timeout)

Comment: `if (user.KodePassword == AppServices.Password)` is not how you do web security! Research *MVC authentication* and *user roles* (or post your final website URL here, so we can hack it in about 15 seconds) :)