# Redirect to login page when the Session is Expired

Tags: angular7, adal.js

I use the adal.js for my angular application. when the session expires getting error in console as :

```
ERROR User login is required
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.windows.net/de08c407-19b9-427d-9fe8-edf254300ca7/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fiboconfigservice.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=828002a4-149f-478c-a318-933ad52b4c4f&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=58558408a18a4ee2a66e82121b92ea60_20190419101323&state=redir%3D%252Fapi%252FCalendar' (redirected from 'https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/ylendar') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

But instead of consolve some error, I would like to redirect a user to login page. how to ahieve that? Is there any provision in adal.js - config?

or any one show me the correct way to take care of this?

here is my config:

```
export function getAdalConfig() {
  return {
    tenant: 'de08ccD7-19b9-427d-9fe8-edf254300ca7',
    clientId: '828002a4-149f-478c-a318-933ad52ererf',
    redirectUri: window.location.origin,
    endpoints: {
      "https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/":"828002a4-149f-478c-a318-233456"
    },
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    expireOffsetSeconds: 600
  };
}
```

Comment: Check 

https://github.com/auth0/auth0-angular/issues/146

Comment: And  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654005/how-to-redirect-to-login-page-when-session-is-expired-asp-net-3-5-formsauthen